# php can't get the POST data

Tags: php, post

My login.php is used for the login request in my system:

```
<?php
// SQL Server Extension Sample Code:
    $connectionInfo = array("UID" => "test", "pwd" => "test", "Database" => "ltests_system", "LoginTimeout" => 30, "Encrypt" => 1, "TrustServerCertificate" => 0);
    $serverName = "tcp:ttestng.database.windows.net,1433";
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $sql = "select * from dbo.driver where username =? and password = ?";
    $query= sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql, array( &$username, &$password));
    if (!$query){
        die( print_r(sqlsrv_errors(),true));
    }

    $response = array();
    $response["success"]=false;

    while(sqlsrv_fetch($query)){
        $response["success"]=true;
        $response["name"]= sqlsrv_get_field($query,1);

    }

    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

However it's not work when I try to apply it to my Android apps.

I've use POSTMAN to try it but still not work.
[image]

```
url: http://localhost:8080/login.php?username=tomfong521&password=password
Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\Apache24\htdocs\login.php on line 7

Notice: Undefined index: password in C:\Apache24\htdocs\login.php on line 8
{"success":false}
```

Also if I change the usernmae and password into hard code not get by POST mehthod, the php request will run correctly

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of postman where you add username and password. You have added something wrong there

Comment: Your variables are sent in a query string in the url, i.e. you can fetch them using `$_GET`, not `$_POST`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to send the post body parameters in the **body** section with `x-www-form-urlencoded` option. Currently, you are actually sending it as GET parameters.
See screenshot for clear idea.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to make var_dump () of $username and $password to see if it already receives the right data.
Also I have the impression that your Postman request is in GET ??

Comment: I've tried both post and get method and still not work

Comment: And I add var_dump ($username); after $_POST, but it echo null value

Comment: On the client side do you send a JSON?